# error with accessing environment variables in vercel. process.env returns "undefined"

Tags: reactjs, deployment, environment-variables, vercel

I am attempting to access a client secret that I added to my project dashboard in Vercel. However, when I access it through my code using process.env, it doesn't return the secret and instead shows "undefined". I have tried some solutions I found online, but they haven't been helpful so far. Just to clarify, my project is built with React and I am pushing it to GitHub, so I cannot store the secret in other files. If anyone who has encountered and resolved this issue could provide a solution, I would greatly appreciate it.
Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

just solved the problem. when using react, environment variables have to be formatted accordingly: REACT_APP_{insert your variable name here}.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).